# Excel - 2-D Bar Chart - Change horizontal axis labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 2-D bar chart in Excel.  I want to change the horizontal axis labels to be different from the data.

Editing the Data Source only changes the vertical axis labels, not the horizontal labels.

How can I change the top horizontal axis labels (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc), so that the eight labels are T1,T2,T1,T2,T3,T1,T2,T3 and appear in the middle of the columns, not on the vertical lines?

[image]

Comment: `T1,T2,T1,T2,T3,T1,T2,T3` <-- Where do these numbers come from? should it not be `T0, T1, T2, T3, T4,...`?

Comment: No, they are university terms abbreviated - Term 1, Term 2 etc, they repeat over 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a helper X-Y scatter line.

Please add the 3 columns, X-value, Y-value and X-Axis as following.

[image]

Then you could select data of X-value and Y-value, create a X-Y scatter line.

Right-click the chart > Chart Design tab > Select data add other two series, Start and End.

[image]

[image]

And then go to Chart Design tab > Change Chart Type > All Charts tab > Combo, set different chart types as below.

[image]

Slect the chart, locate to Chart Design > Add Chart Element > Axes > Choose all Horizontal and Vertical axes to show.

[image]

Please choose the Secondary Horizontal, set it across 0.

[image]

Choose the Secondary Vertical, set it across 0 too.

[image]

If needed you may also choose Primary Vertical, then set its values in reverse order.

[image]

Juest keep the Secondary Horizontal, add lable for X-Y scatter line. Choose one lable, enter "=" in Formula Bar, click C14 (the lable you need, on my sample, the lables are not right), press Enter.

[image]

[image]